# Should I use Ingress vs LoadBalancer for Kubernetes on Google Cloud (with custom domain and an SSL certificate)?

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, custom-domain

According to [this page](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/google-managed-certs), it appears Google Kubernetes can make a Google managed SSL certificate if you're using LoadBalancer. That's what I want to use.

However, I used [this page](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/configuring-domain-name-static-ip) to set up an Ingress for my custom domain.

So right now, I have an Ingress and I can access my cluster using my custom domain just fine, but how do I add HTTPS to it? My suspicion is that Ingress also makes a LoadBalancer, but I can't figure out how to modify it according to the first link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My suspicion is that Ingress also makes a LoadBalancer, but I can't
> figure out how to modify it according to the first link.

You're right. When you create an **ingress** object, **load balancer** is created automatically, behind the scenes. It's even mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/configuring-domain-name-static-ip):

> If you choose to expose your application using an
> [Ingress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress),
> which creates an HTTP(S) Load Balancer, you must [reserve a global
> static IP
> address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#reserve_new_static).

You can even list it in your **Google Cloud Console** by goint to `Navigation menu` -> `Networking` -> `Network services` -> `Load balancing`.

The easiest way to edit it is by clicking 3 dots next to it and then `Edit`:

[image]

But rather than editing it manually you need to modify your `Ingress` resource.

Suppose you have followed the steps outlined [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/configuring-domain-name-static-ip#step_2b_using_an_ingress) and everything works as expected, but only via **http**, which is also expected as you have not configured **SSL Certificate** with your ingress so far and the **Load Balancer** it uses behind the scenes is also configured to work with http only.

If you followed [the guide you mentioned](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/google-managed-certs) and have already configured **Google-managed SSL certificate**, you only need to update your **ingress** resource configuration by adding `networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: certificate-name` annotation as @ldg suggested in his answer.

If you didn't configure your SSL certificate, you can do it from kubernetes level by applying the following yaml manifest as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs):

```
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1beta2
kind: ManagedCertificate
metadata:
  name: example-cert
spec:
  domains:
    - example.com
```

Save it as file `example-cert.yaml` and then run:

```
kubectl apply -f example-cert.yaml
```

Once it is created you can re-apply your **ingress** configuration from the same yaml manifest as before with the mentioned annotation added.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: helloweb
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: helloweb-ip
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: example-cert ### 
  labels:
    app: hello
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: helloweb-backend
    servicePort: 8080
```

If for some reason you want to get the ingress you've deployed based on your running configuration, you can run:

```
kubectl get ingress helloweb -o yaml > ingress.yaml
```

then you can edit the `ingress.yaml` file and re-apply it again.

After adding the annotation, go again in your **Google Cloud Console** to `Navigation menu` -> `Networking` -> `Network services` -> `Load balancing` and you'll notice that the **protocol** of the **load balancer** associated with the ingress have changed from `HTTP` to `HTTP(S)` and if the certificate is valid, you should be able to access your website using your custom domain via HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to have 2 Load balancers to achieve your goal, first one is for HTTP with redirection and the other is for HTTPS. You can check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-http-https-redirect) for the official guide on setting up HTTPS load balancers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to associate the managed cert to your ingress manifest. Where you are setting the value for `kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name` you should be able to add `networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: *certificate-name*`

see: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs

The example ingress (from those docs) looks like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-name
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: address-name
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: certificate-name
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: service-name
    servicePort: service-port
```

Yours might look slightly different, but the important part for this feature is the annotations section.

Comment: Is `apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1` (not `networking.gke.io`) the same thing?

Comment: Okay, doesn't seem to make a difference. Thanks for such a concise answer!